# Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.wallet.PaymentDataRequest

Tags: android, braintree, google-pay

in Android app，i add BrainTree sdk，but i got a problem OR_BIBED_07 and got some log below:

[image]

it show me this error in product environment, but i can pay in test  environment Since this is the first time to access this sdk i do not know how to deal with it

[image]

According to the BrainTree official document，should  i do this？

Then you'll need to follow Google's documentation for gaining access to the Google Payment API production environment and submitting your app for review.

i try to search and have a look at BrainTree official document but i do not know how to deal with it